# Порядковый номер записи в mysql с учетом сортировки

Tags: mysql

Как в mysql узнать порядковый номер искомой записи с учетом сортировки по полю value order DESC?
Тобишь на примере выполнения:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value ASC WHERE id='10'
```

Сама таблица бд имеет следующие записи

```
id value
16 5
5 4
3 3
10 2
7 1
```

Можно ли как то получить порядковый номер который равен 2-м?

Comment: А почему не сразу выбрать через where? В чем смысл такого финта ушами?

Comment: А как на примере оператора WHERE можно узнать "ПОРЯДКОВЫЙ" номер записи?

Comment: Имеется в виду `id=2` или вторая строка в результирующем наборе?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1,1` оно ?

Comment: Ну вот представьте что в таблице 10 записей, и на основе сортировки DESC/ASC каждый раз выдается разный результат (порядковый номер). То есть этот запрос будет в цикле выполняться (Да-да, быдлокод, ну что поделать).

Comment: Подправил запрос

Comment: В случае ASC порядковый номер = 2, в случае DESC порядковый номер равен 4

Comment: Кажется, что-то Вы недоговариваете. Если у Вас `id` уникальные то запрос `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value ASC WHERE id='10'` вернёт только одну запись независимо от сортировки.

Comment: Теперь из вашего вопроса вообще ничего непонятно. Вы выбираете через `WHERE id='10'` который уже выбирает `value = 2`. Причем тут сортировка? Кстати выборку по числу правильно писать без кавычек `WHERE id=10`

Comment: @asd в mysql вроде нет такого понятия как порядок хранения, обычно данные хранятся в том порядке в каком они добавлялись, но нет гарантий что результат запроса выдаст именно этот порядок. Поэтому для явного указания порядка выдачи, используется оператор ORDER BY. На сколько я понял ваш вопрос, то вам необходимо пронумеровать результат выдачи. Обычно результат запроса к базе данных разбирают через цикл, в логику этого цикла можно включить простой счетчик и добавлять его к итоговым результатам. Таким образом вы получите пронумерованный, отсортированный список.

Answer (score 2):

Не увидел решения вопроса, поэтому на будущее, может кому понадобится.

Этот запрос нумерует все записи:

```
SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS row_number, table.value as val
FROM table, (select @i:=0) AS z)
```

В случае, если сделать к нему еще один запрос, фильтруя по необходимым полям, можно добиться желаемого результата:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS row_number, table.value as val
FROM table ORDER BY table.value ASC, (select @i:=0) AS z) as m WHERE val=2;
```