# Как получить id строки?

Tags: mysql, sql

Моя проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно получить номер(`id`) строки в базе данных.

Comment: `SELECT id FROM table`?

Comment: какой строки, какие данные про строку известны

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Порядковый номер записи в mysql с учетом сортировки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524655/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-mysql-%d1%81-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. в MySQL нет row_number, можете номер строки вывести таким образом:

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 as rank,
    c.*
from table_name c, (select @rank:=0) r
```