# Взять номер позиции из MySQL в результате запроса

Tags: mysql, запрос

Есть таблица **test_table** вида:

```
==============
id  |   score
==============
1   |   22222
2   |   33333
3   |   789877
4   |   444
5   |   555
```

Как одним запросом получить позицию для специфического **id** с применением сортировки по полю **score** в порядке **DESC**? Мне нужно выводить для каждого игрока его текущую позицию по его текущему результату.

Я пробовал такой вариант из поиска, но результат не тот. Номер позиции всегда равен 1.

```
SELECT @n:=@n+1 AS row_number, score FROM (SELECT @n:=0, score FROM test_table t1 WHERE id=4 ORDER by score DESC) t2;
```

Пробовал решение из [схожего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524655/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B2-mysql-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8) но получаю ошибку.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS row_number, test_table.id as id
FROM test_table ORDER BY test_table.score DESC, (select @i:=0) AS z) as m WHERE id=4;
```

Ошибка

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'AS z) as m WHERE val=4' at line 3

Comment: Начните с обнародования версии MySQL.

Comment: @Akina самая популярная в народе 5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работает с версии 5.x и выше:

```
Select 
  @I:=@I+1 as row_number 
  score,
from 
  `test_table `,
  (SELECT @I := 0) tt 
order by 
  Score DESC
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: 
Если нужен только один ID:

```
Select 
    row_number,
    Score 
from(
    Select 
        @I:=@I+1 as row_number ,
        score,
        ID
    from 
        `test_table`,
        (SELECT @I := 0) tt 
    order by 
        Score DESC
    ) dd 
where ID=1
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо работает как нужно. А самое главное понятно что вы написали.